# Displaying Functions values?

Tags: c++, function

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int hwGrades();
int testGrades();
int projectGrade();


int main(){

 hwGrades();
 testGrades();
 projectGrade();
 //I want the average of each function displayed here


}

int hwGrades(){
  int hw1,hw2,hw3, hwAverage;

  cout << "Enter the grades of your homework." << endl;

  cout << "Homework 1: ";
  cin >> hw1;

  cout << "Homework 2: ";
  cin >> hw2;

  cout << "Homework 3: ";
  cin >> hw3;

  hwAverage = (hw1 + hw2 + hw3) / 3;
  return hwAverage;
}
int testGrades(){
  int test1, test2, test3, testAvgerage;
  cout << "Enter the grades for the tests." << endl;

    cout << "Test 1: "; 
    cin >> test1;

    cout << "Test 2: ";
    cin >> test2;

   cout << "Test 3: ";
   cin >> test3;

 testAvgerage = (test1 + test2 + test3)/3;
  return testAvgerage;
}
int projectGrade(){
  int project;
    cout << "What did you get on your project: ";
    cin >> project;
  return project;
}
```

I'm having trouble understanding this, after all the function are completed how do I display the values inputted by the user? I tried parameters but I don't have a great grasp of it. Any help would be appreciated. I mostly understand otherwise, I just don't get how to use the values after the function is done.

Comment: You should be using doubles for your averages. By using int you are limiting your average values to whole numbers, which loses a whole lot of precision.

Comment: Either make global variables or use a `class`/`struct`, then you can display those variables easily. There is one more approach, you can call the function to display the values inside function where you take inputs, by passing the input as parameter into the function each time you take one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print the values inputed by the user  you need to print them in the functions were you read them.

If you refer to the calculated values returned from the functions like `testGrades()` you can store the return value in a variable do something like this

```
int result = testGrades();
cout << result;
```

Or you can output directly the resturn value of the function

```
cout << testGrades();
```